# Angular route does not load one partial

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

One of the partials I am using in my Angular app does not load, even though it can be loaded by the browser directly.

Here is my routing configuration:

```
BlankApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/overview', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/overview.html'
        })
        .when('/howitworks', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/howitworks.html'
        })
        .when('/startnow', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/startnow.html',
            controller: 'AdsCtrl'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html'
        })
        .when('/ads', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/ads.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/overview'
        });
}]);
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" theme="forest" aria-label="nav">
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/overview" name="overview">Übersicht</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/howitworks" name="howitworks">So funktioniert's</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/startnow" name="startnow">Jetzt loslegen</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/profile" name="profile">Firmendaten</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/ads" name="ads">Werbungen</md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>
</div>
```

It works fine for profile.html but cannot find ads.html, even though it is present and can be viewed with Chrome.

[image: Dev Tools output]

I tried clearing the browser cache already, but it did not help. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Check whether templateUrl: 'partials/ads.html' is present there... in partials folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the partial file's name. It contains the word "ads", which is obviously filtered by an ad blocker (AdBlock or Google's own). I renamed the file and it's working ok.